# How do I offset the Victory-native VictoryAxis grid display? I can add padding for the graph but can't find how to add it for the background grid

Tags: grid, styles, victory-charts, victory-native

[image: Victory Graph] I want that the background grid starts at the same time that the line starts. I can't seem to separate the grid lines from vertical axis.

but I have tried several different things padding, margin... in the different styles options such as grid and axis.
   `<VictoryChart domainPadding={10}> {/* Y-Axis */} <VictoryAxis dependentAxis width={400} height={400} offsetY={200} standalone={false} tickFormat={(t) =>`${t}`}

```
    style={{
      axis: {

        stroke: theme.colors.grey,
      },
      axisLabel: {
        fontSize: theme.sizes.fontSizes.bodySmall,
        padding: theme.spaces.medium,
      },
      grid: {
        stroke: theme.colors.grey,
        strokeDasharray: 4,
      },

      tickLabels: {
        fontFamily: theme.fonts.regular.fontFamily,
        fontSize: theme.sizes.fontSizes.bodySmall,
        padding: theme.spaces.moderate,
        fontStyle: theme.fonts.regular.fontWeight,
      },
    }}
  />`
```

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I figured it out.

one solution to offset the grid line you need to access the grid property and use transform:

```
 grid: {
        stroke: theme.colors.grey,
        strokeDasharray: 4,
        transform: 'translateX(2.5%) scale(0.95,1) '
      },
```